# Datatables.net slow in rendering and applying paging

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am trying to implement DataTables.net 1.10.9 (http://datatables.net) in asp.net web forms. Its works great with small amount of data but it delays rendering and applying paging on web page.

I am using Repeater control and binding it in code behind page at runtime.

When page is loaded, i can see all the data in table but page is still in process and after 5-8 seconds delay paging and theme is applied on the table.

Is there any work around to reduce the rending time? (without using server side webservice)

So far i have tried using "deferRender": true but no luck.

Working okay in firefox and google chrome but delay is in IE9

Comment: How many rows are in the table when it's rendered?

Comment: Looks like there is a issue with IE when using innerHtml

 http://love2dev.com/#!article/Slow-Rendering-with-Large-Tables-in-IE-9-amp-8  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406192/how-to-speed-up-the-reading-of-innerhtml-in-ie8

Answer (score 7):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`deferRender`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender) to  defer rendering of non-visible rows for additional speed of initialization.

Please note that this will improve performance only for Ajax or JavaScript sourced data (i.e. when using `ajax` or `data` options).

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    deferRender: true
});
```

If you're using HTML sourced data, consider writing a script that will produce JSON with the data. Then you can specify the path to the script with `ajax` option and use `deferRender: true` as shown above to improve performance.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqx5Loop/) for code and demonstration.

> **LINKS**

- [Deferred rendering for speed](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html)

Comment: @user1263981, please edit your question and state what you've tried so far along with DataTables initialization code and corresponding HTML markup.

Comment: I am not using ajax or server side processing as mentioned in question.

Comment: @user1263981, it wasn't clear from the question. So all your data is in HTML, right?

Comment: Repeater control with html table are in asp.net page and i am binding repeater control through datasource (datatable in .net) at runtime.

Comment: I have tested in firefox and google chrome and its working fine but delay is in IE9.

Comment: @user1263981. the only solution I see is to separate data and content and write a script that will produce JSON with the data. Then you can specify the path to the script in `ajax` option and use `deferRender: true` to improve performance.